# Is there a sql alchemy operation to add a record, but check for dupes?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I write lots of code using sql alchemy on top of postgres 9.3. I often have to do an insert, after checking that the record does not already exist. To do so, I do the following

```
c = session.query(ClassName).filter(ClassName.id=new.id).count() 
if c==0:
    session.add(new)
    session.commit()
```

This is sort of tedious. Is there any way to set up sql alchemy + postgres to handle that checking automatically? I'm not necessarily looking for a unique-ness index in postgres (which will throw an error if the record already exists) so much as an "add" operation that knows what to do if a record is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define your own

> "add" operation that knows what to do if a record is already there.

?

```
def addIfNotExist(session, new):
    if not c:
        session.add(new)
        session.commit()
    else:
        pass #put other code here if needed

addIfNotExist(session, new)
```

Without putting a unique index on `id`, this is the most direct thing I can think of, as there isn't (to my knowledge) a built in way of doing what you want to do